# Error when attempting to buffer video in opencv using multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I'm trying to read video into a buffer using threads in OpenCV and I get "`Assertion fctx->async_lock failed at libavcodec/pthread_frame.c:167`" the reason I want to use threads to do this is so I can read a lot of frames into a list at a time so it's fast. I need all the frames and can not skip any frames. I thought multi-threading would be the way to go. my code works single-threaded aka with "`buffer_refill = 1`".

```
import threading
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('data/temp/testing/test.mp4')
frames = []
total_frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
frames_left = total_frames
threads = []

print(total_frames)

min_buffer = 120
buffer_refill = 60

def buffer():
    print('buffer')
    frame = cap.grab()
    ret, frame = cap.retrieve()
    frames.append(frame)

def get_buffer(num):
    global frames_left
    for i in range(num):
        frames_left -= 1
        if frames_left > 0:
            t = threading.Thread(target=buffer)
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    print('block')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    if frames_left > 0 and len(frames) < min_buffer:
        get_buffer(buffer_refill)
    else:
        cv2.imshow('Frame',frames[0])
        frames.pop(0)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: that's not how any of this works. please stop. video reading is inherently sequential, and WILL FAIL if you do what you do there, with multiple threads trying to read from the video object at the same time. DO NOT DO THIS. it's wrong. -- if the backend is ffmpeg, decoding is probably already using multiple threads, so you don't have to do anything.

Comment: what you _can_ do is spawn _one thread_ that does video reading (NOT a single read per thread, ONE thread, living very long) and feeding into a queue, blocking if the queue is full. -- in case anyone's considering turning that into an answer, just poke me instead.

Comment: that approach *still* isn't guaranteed to be faster because the `VideoCapture` already runs multithreaded (ffmpeg). -- you should just stick to simple code. you've got no reason to complicate it like this.